# C stack usage error with SQL in R notebook

Tags: sql, r, r-markdown

**Problem**

I just started using R notebooks and was impressed with being able to use SQL chunks. However I have run into a bizarre problem.

My code within the notebook looks something like the following

````
```{r}
library(RSQLite)
library(plyr)
library(Matrix)
```

```{r}
sessionInfo()
```

```{r}
dbName = '/home/my_db.db'
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname=dbName)
```

```{sql connection=db, max.print=10}
SELECT * FROM EVENTS_ID
```
````

The error I get is

```
Error: C stack usage  7969396 is too close to the limit
Failed to execute SQL chunk
```

Now I have a further SQL query further in the notebook that when executed gives a similar error with a different number,

```
Error: C stack usage  7969604 is too close to the limit
Failed to execute SQL chunk
```

The most strange thing about this however is that the code was running fine previously and I've made no changes that I can think of.

**Attempted Solutions/Debugging**

1) Restarted computer. Still get the same errors.

2) Changed the code to the following to rule out database table error

````
```{sql connection=db}
SELECT 1
```
````

Still got the same error.

**Current Workaround**

I can workaround the issue by doing everything in R instead of the SQL chunk i.e.

````
```{r}
query <- gsub(pattern='\\s',replacement=" ",x="SELECT * FROM EVENTS_ID LIMIT 10")
dbGetQuery(db, query)
```
````

This works but I would like to use the SQL chunks if possible.

**Further Info**

When running `traceback()` after the error I get the following which may suggest there is some kind of `as.vector` recursion error

```
936: as.vector(x, mode)
935: as.vector(x, mode)
934: as.vector(x, mode)
933: as.vector(x, mode)
932: as.vector(x, mode)
931: as.vector(x, mode)
930: as.vector(x, mode)
929: as.vector(x, mode)
928: as.vector(x, mode)
927: as.vector(x, mode)
926: as.vector(x, mode)
925: as.vector(x, mode)
924: as.vector(x, mode)
923: as.vector(x, mode)
922: as.vector(x, mode)
921: as.vector(x, mode)
920: as.vector(x, mode)
919: as.vector(x, mode)
918: as.vector(x, mode)
917: as.vector(x, mode)
916: as.vector(x, mode)
915: as.vector(x, mode)
914: as.vector(x, mode)
913: as.vector(x, mode)
912: as.vector(x, mode)
911: as.vector(x, mode)
910: as.vector(x, mode)
909: as.vector(x, mode)
908: as.vector(x, mode)
907: as.vector(x, mode)
906: as.vector(x, mode)
905: as.vector(x, mode)
904: as.vector(x, mode)
903: as.vector(x, mode)
902: as.vector(x, mode)
901: as.vector(x, mode)
900: as.vector(x, mode)
899: as.vector(x, mode)
898: as.vector(x, mode)
897: as.vector(x, mode)
896: as.vector(x, mode)
895: as.vector(x, mode)
894: as.vector(x, mode)
893: as.vector(x, mode)
892: as.vector(x, mode)
891: as.vector(x, mode)
890: as.vector(x, mode)
889: as.vector(x, mode)
888: as.vector(x, mode)
887: as.vector(x, mode)
886: as.vector(x, mode)
885: as.vector(x, mode)
884: as.vector(x, mode)
883: as.vector(x, mode)
882: as.vector(x, mode)
881: as.vector(x, mode)
880: as.vector(x, mode)
879: as.vector(x, mode)
878: as.vector(x, mode)
877: as.vector(x, mode)
876: as.vector(x, mode)
875: as.vector(x, mode)
874: as.vector(x, mode)
873: as.vector(x, mode)
872: as.vector(x, mode)
871: as.vector(x, mode)
870: as.vector(x, mode)
869: as.vector(x, mode)
868: as.vector(x, mode)
867: as.vector(x, mode)
866: as.vector(x, mode)
865: as.vector(x, mode)
864: as.vector(x, mode)
863: as.vector(x, mode)
862: as.vector(x, mode)
861: as.vector(x, mode)
860: as.vector(x, mode)
859: as.vector(x, mode)
858: as.vector(x, mode)
857: as.vector(x, mode)
856: as.vector(x, mode)
855: as.vector(x, mode)
854: as.vector(x, mode)
853: as.vector(x, mode)
852: as.vector(x, mode)
851: as.vector(x, mode)
850: as.vector(x, mode)
849: as.vector(x, mode)
848: as.vector(x, mode)
847: as.vector(x, mode)
846: as.vector(x, mode)
845: as.vector(x, mode)
844: as.vector(x, mode)
843: as.vector(x, mode)
842: as.vector(x, mode)
841: as.vector(x, mode)
840: as.vector(x, mode)
839: as.vector(x, mode)
838: as.vector(x, mode)
837: as.vector(x, mode)
836: as.vector(x, mode)
835: as.vector(x, mode)
834: as.vector(x, mode)
833: as.vector(x, mode)
832: as.vector(x, mode)
831: as.vector(x, mode)
830: as.vector(x, mode)
829: as.vector(x, mode)
828: as.vector(x, mode)
827: as.vector(x, mode)
826: as.vector(x, mode)
825: as.vector(x, mode)
824: as.vector(x, mode)
823: as.vector(x, mode)
822: as.vector(x, mode)
821: as.vector(x, mode)
820: as.vector(x, mode)
819: as.vector(x, mode)
818: as.vector(x, mode)
817: as.vector(x, mode)
816: as.vector(x, mode)
815: as.vector(x, mode)
814: as.vector(x, mode)
813: as.vector(x, mode)
812: as.vector(x, mode)
811: as.vector(x, mode)
810: as.vector(x, mode)
809: as.vector(x, mode)
808: as.vector(x, mode)
807: as.vector(x, mode)
806: as.vector(x, mode)
805: as.vector(x, mode)
804: as.vector(x, mode)
803: as.vector(x, mode)
802: as.vector(x, mode)
801: as.vector(x, mode)
800: as.vector(x, mode)
799: as.vector(x, mode)
798: as.vector(x, mode)
797: as.vector(x, mode)
796: as.vector(x, mode)
795: as.vector(x, mode)
794: as.vector(x, mode)
793: as.vector(x, mode)
792: as.vector(x, mode)
791: as.vector(x, mode)
790: as.vector(x, mode)
789: as.vector(x, mode)
788: as.vector(x, mode)
787: as.vector(x, mode)
786: as.vector(x, mode)
785: as.vector(x, mode)
784: as.vector(x, mode)
783: as.vector(x, mode)
782: as.vector(x, mode)
781: as.vector(x, mode)
780: as.vector(x, mode)
779: as.vector(x, mode)
778: as.vector(x, mode)
777: as.vector(x, mode)
776: as.vector(x, mode)
775: as.vector(x, mode)
774: as.vector(x, mode)
773: as.vector(x, mode)
772: as.vector(x, mode)
771: as.vector(x, mode)
770: as.vector(x, mode)
769: as.vector(x, mode)
768: as.vector(x, mode)
767: as.vector(x, mode)
766: as.vector(x, mode)
765: as.vector(x, mode)
764: as.vector(x, mode)
763: as.vector(x, mode)
762: as.vector(x, mode)
761: as.vector(x, mode)
760: as.vector(x, mode)
759: as.vector(x, mode)
758: as.vector(x, mode)
757: as.vector(x, mode)
756: as.vector(x, mode)
755: as.vector(x, mode)
754: as.vector(x, mode)
753: as.vector(x, mode)
752: as.vector(x, mode)
751: as.vector(x, mode)
750: as.vector(x, mode)
749: as.vector(x, mode)
748: as.vector(x, mode)
747: as.vector(x, mode)
746: as.vector(x, mode)
745: as.vector(x, mode)
744: as.vector(x, mode)
743: as.vector(x, mode)
742: as.vector(x, mode)
741: as.vector(x, mode)
740: as.vector(x, mode)
739: as.vector(x, mode)
738: as.vector(x, mode)
737: as.vector(x, mode)
736: as.vector(x, mode)
735: as.vector(x, mode)
734: as.vector(x, mode)
733: as.vector(x, mode)
732: as.vector(x, mode)
731: as.vector(x, mode)
730: as.vector(x, mode)
729: as.vector(x, mode)
728: as.vector(x, mode)
727: as.vector(x, mode)
726: as.vector(x, mode)
725: as.vector(x, mode)
724: as.vector(x, mode)
723: as.vector(x, mode)
722: as.vector(x, mode)
721: as.vector(x, mode)
720: as.vector(x, mode)
719: as.vector(x, mode)
718: as.vector(x, mode)
717: as.vector(x, mode)
716: as.vector(x, mode)
715: as.vector(x, mode)
714: as.vector(x, mode)
713: as.vector(x, mode)
712: as.vector(x, mode)
711: as.vector(x, mode)
710: as.vector(x, mode)
709: as.vector(x, mode)
708: as.vector(x, mode)
707: as.vector(x, mode)
706: as.vector(x, mode)
705: as.vector(x, mode)
704: as.vector(x, mode)
703: as.vector(x, mode)
702: as.vector(x, mode)
701: as.vector(x, mode)
700: as.vector(x, mode)
699: as.vector(x, mode)
698: as.vector(x, mode)
697: as.vector(x, mode)
696: as.vector(x, mode)
695: as.vector(x, mode)
694: as.vector(x, mode)
693: as.vector(x, mode)
692: as.vector(x, mode)
691: as.vector(x, mode)
690: as.vector(x, mode)
689: as.vector(x, mode)
688: as.vector(x, mode)
687: as.vector(x, mode)
686: as.vector(x, mode)
685: as.vector(x, mode)
684: as.vector(x, mode)
683: as.vector(x, mode)
682: as.vector(x, mode)
681: as.vector(x, mode)
680: as.vector(x, mode)
679: as.vector(x, mode)
678: as.vector(x, mode)
677: as.vector(x, mode)
676: as.vector(x, mode)
675: as.vector(x, mode)
674: as.vector(x, mode)
673: as.vector(x, mode)
672: as.vector(x, mode)
671: as.vector(x, mode)
670: as.vector(x, mode)
669: as.vector(x, mode)
668: as.vector(x, mode)
667: as.vector(x, mode)
666: as.vector(x, mode)
665: as.vector(x, mode)
664: as.vector(x, mode)
663: as.vector(x, mode)
662: as.vector(x, mode)
661: as.vector(x, mode)
660: as.vector(x, mode)
659: as.vector(x, mode)
658: as.vector(x, mode)
657: as.vector(x, mode)
656: as.vector(x, mode)
655: as.vector(x, mode)
654: as.vector(x, mode)
653: as.vector(x, mode)
652: as.vector(x, mode)
651: as.vector(x, mode)
650: as.vector(x, mode)
649: as.vector(x, mode)
648: as.vector(x, mode)
647: as.vector(x, mode)
646: as.vector(x, mode)
645: as.vector(x, mode)
644: as.vector(x, mode)
643: as.vector(x, mode)
642: as.vector(x, mode)
641: as.vector(x, mode)
640: as.vector(x, mode)
639: as.vector(x, mode)
638: as.vector(x, mode)
637: as.vector(x, mode)
636: as.vector(x, mode)
635: as.vector(x, mode)
634: as.vector(x, mode)
633: as.vector(x, mode)
632: as.vector(x, mode)
631: as.vector(x, mode)
630: as.vector(x, mode)
629: as.vector(x, mode)
628: as.vector(x, mode)
627: as.vector(x, mode)
626: as.vector(x, mode)
625: as.vector(x, mode)
624: as.vector(x, mode)
623: as.vector(x, mode)
622: as.vector(x, mode)
621: as.vector(x, mode)
620: as.vector(x, mode)
619: as.vector(x, mode)
618: as.vector(x, mode)
617: as.vector(x, mode)
616: as.vector(x, mode)
615: as.vector(x, mode)
614: as.vector(x, mode)
613: as.vector(x, mode)
612: as.vector(x, mode)
611: as.vector(x, mode)
610: as.vector(x, mode)
609: as.vector(x, mode)
608: as.vector(x, mode)
607: as.vector(x, mode)
606: as.vector(x, mode)
605: as.vector(x, mode)
604: as.vector(x, mode)
603: as.vector(x, mode)
602: as.vector(x, mode)
601: as.vector(x, mode)
600: as.vector(x, mode)
599: as.vector(x, mode)
598: as.vector(x, mode)
597: as.vector(x, mode)
596: as.vector(x, mode)
595: as.vector(x, mode)
594: as.vector(x, mode)
593: as.vector(x, mode)
592: as.vector(x, mode)
591: as.vector(x, mode)
590: as.vector(x, mode)
589: as.vector(x, mode)
588: as.vector(x, mode)
587: as.vector(x, mode)
586: as.vector(x, mode)
585: as.vector(x, mode)
584: as.vector(x, mode)
583: as.vector(x, mode)
582: as.vector(x, mode)
581: as.vector(x, mode)
580: as.vector(x, mode)
579: as.vector(x, mode)
578: as.vector(x, mode)
577: as.vector(x, mode)
576: as.vector(x, mode)
575: as.vector(x, mode)
574: as.vector(x, mode)
573: as.vector(x, mode)
572: as.vector(x, mode)
571: as.vector(x, mode)
570: as.vector(x, mode)
569: as.vector(x, mode)
568: as.vector(x, mode)
567: as.vector(x, mode)
566: as.vector(x, mode)
565: as.vector(x, mode)
564: as.vector(x, mode)
563: as.vector(x, mode)
562: as.vector(x, mode)
561: as.vector(x, mode)
560: as.vector(x, mode)
559: as.vector(x, mode)
558: as.vector(x, mode)
557: as.vector(x, mode)
556: as.vector(x, mode)
555: as.vector(x, mode)
554: as.vector(x, mode)
553: as.vector(x, mode)
552: as.vector(x, mode)
551: as.vector(x, mode)
550: as.vector(x, mode)
549: as.vector(x, mode)
548: as.vector(x, mode)
547: as.vector(x, mode)
546: as.vector(x, mode)
545: as.vector(x, mode)
544: as.vector(x, mode)
543: as.vector(x, mode)
542: as.vector(x, mode)
541: as.vector(x, mode)
540: as.vector(x, mode)
539: as.vector(x, mode)
538: as.vector(x, mode)
537: as.vector(x, mode)
536: as.vector(x, mode)
535: as.vector(x, mode)
534: as.vector(x, mode)
533: as.vector(x, mode)
532: as.vector(x, mode)
531: as.vector(x, mode)
530: as.vector(x, mode)
529: as.vector(x, mode)
528: as.vector(x, mode)
527: as.vector(x, mode)
526: as.vector(x, mode)
525: as.vector(x, mode)
524: as.vector(x, mode)
523: as.vector(x, mode)
522: as.vector(x, mode)
521: as.vector(x, mode)
520: as.vector(x, mode)
519: as.vector(x, mode)
518: as.vector(x, mode)
517: as.vector(x, mode)
516: as.vector(x, mode)
515: as.vector(x, mode)
514: as.vector(x, mode)
513: as.vector(x, mode)
512: as.vector(x, mode)
511: as.vector(x, mode)
510: as.vector(x, mode)
509: as.vector(x, mode)
508: as.vector(x, mode)
507: as.vector(x, mode)
506: as.vector(x, mode)
505: as.vector(x, mode)
504: as.vector(x, mode)
503: as.vector(x, mode)
502: as.vector(x, mode)
501: as.vector(x, mode)
500: as.vector(x, mode)
499: as.vector(x, mode)
498: as.vector(x, mode)
497: as.vector(x, mode)
496: as.vector(x, mode)
495: as.vector(x, mode)
494: as.vector(x, mode)
493: as.vector(x, mode)
492: as.vector(x, mode)
491: as.vector(x, mode)
490: as.vector(x, mode)
489: as.vector(x, mode)
488: as.vector(x, mode)
487: as.vector(x, mode)
486: as.vector(x, mode)
485: as.vector(x, mode)
484: as.vector(x, mode)
483: as.vector(x, mode)
482: as.vector(x, mode)
481: as.vector(x, mode)
480: as.vector(x, mode)
479: as.vector(x, mode)
478: as.vector(x, mode)
477: as.vector(x, mode)
476: as.vector(x, mode)
475: as.vector(x, mode)
474: as.vector(x, mode)
473: as.vector(x, mode)
472: as.vector(x, mode)
471: as.vector(x, mode)
470: as.vector(x, mode)
469: as.vector(x, mode)
468: as.vector(x, mode)
467: as.vector(x, mode)
466: as.vector(x, mode)
465: as.vector(x, mode)
464: as.vector(x, mode)
463: as.vector(x, mode)
462: as.vector(x, mode)
461: as.vector(x, mode)
460: as.vector(x, mode)
459: as.vector(x, mode)
458: as.vector(x, mode)
457: as.vector(x, mode)
456: as.vector(x, mode)
455: as.vector(x, mode)
454: as.vector(x, mode)
453: as.vector(x, mode)
452: as.vector(x, mode)
451: as.vector(x, mode)
450: as.vector(x, mode)
449: as.vector(x, mode)
448: as.vector(x, mode)
447: as.vector(x, mode)
446: as.vector(x, mode)
445: as.vector(x, mode)
444: as.vector(x, mode)
443: as.vector(x, mode)
442: as.vector(x, mode)
441: as.vector(x, mode)
440: as.vector(x, mode)
439: as.vector(x, mode)
438: as.vector(x, mode)
437: as.vector(x, mode)
436: as.vector(x, mode)
435: as.vector(x, mode)
434: as.vector(x, mode)
433: as.vector(x, mode)
432: as.vector(x, mode)
431: as.vector(x, mode)
430: as.vector(x, mode)
429: as.vector(x, mode)
428: as.vector(x, mode)
427: as.vector(x, mode)
426: as.vector(x, mode)
425: as.vector(x, mode)
424: as.vector(x, mode)
423: as.vector(x, mode)
422: as.vector(x, mode)
421: as.vector(x, mode)
420: as.vector(x, mode)
419: as.vector(x, mode)
418: as.vector(x, mode)
417: as.vector(x, mode)
416: as.vector(x, mode)
415: as.vector(x, mode)
414: as.vector(x, mode)
413: as.vector(x, mode)
412: as.vector(x, mode)
411: as.vector(x, mode)
410: as.vector(x, mode)
409: as.vector(x, mode)
408: as.vector(x, mode)
407: as.vector(x, mode)
406: as.vector(x, mode)
405: as.vector(x, mode)
404: as.vector(x, mode)
403: as.vector(x, mode)
402: as.vector(x, mode)
401: as.vector(x, mode)
400: as.vector(x, mode)
399: as.vector(x, mode)
398: as.vector(x, mode)
397: as.vector(x, mode)
396: as.vector(x, mode)
395: as.vector(x, mode)
394: as.vector(x, mode)
393: as.vector(x, mode)
392: as.vector(x, mode)
391: as.vector(x, mode)
390: as.vector(x, mode)
389: as.vector(x, mode)
388: as.vector(x, mode)
387: as.vector(x, mode)
386: as.vector(x, mode)
385: as.vector(x, mode)
384: as.vector(x, mode)
383: as.vector(x, mode)
382: as.vector(x, mode)
381: as.vector(x, mode)
380: as.vector(x, mode)
379: as.vector(x, mode)
378: as.vector(x, mode)
377: as.vector(x, mode)
376: as.vector(x, mode)
375: as.vector(x, mode)
374: as.vector(x, mode)
373: as.vector(x, mode)
372: as.vector(x, mode)
371: as.vector(x, mode)
370: as.vector(x, mode)
369: as.vector(x, mode)
368: as.vector(x, mode)
367: as.vector(x, mode)
366: as.vector(x, mode)
365: as.vector(x, mode)
364: as.vector(x, mode)
363: as.vector(x, mode)
362: as.vector(x, mode)
361: as.vector(x, mode)
360: as.vector(x, mode)
359: as.vector(x, mode)
358: as.vector(x, mode)
357: as.vector(x, mode)
356: as.vector(x, mode)
355: as.vector(x, mode)
354: as.vector(x, mode)
353: as.vector(x, mode)
352: as.vector(x, mode)
351: as.vector(x, mode)
350: as.vector(x, mode)
349: as.vector(x, mode)
348: as.vector(x, mode)
347: as.vector(x, mode)
346: as.vector(x, mode)
345: as.vector(x, mode)
344: as.vector(x, mode)
343: as.vector(x, mode)
342: as.vector(x, mode)
341: as.vector(x, mode)
340: as.vector(x, mode)
339: as.vector(x, mode)
338: as.vector(x, mode)
337: as.vector(x, mode)
336: as.vector(x, mode)
335: as.vector(x, mode)
334: as.vector(x, mode)
333: as.vector(x, mode)
332: as.vector(x, mode)
331: as.vector(x, mode)
330: as.vector(x, mode)
329: as.vector(x, mode)
328: as.vector(x, mode)
327: as.vector(x, mode)
326: as.vector(x, mode)
325: as.vector(x, mode)
324: as.vector(x, mode)
323: as.vector(x, mode)
322: as.vector(x, mode)
321: as.vector(x, mode)
320: as.vector(x, mode)
319: as.vector(x, mode)
318: as.vector(x, mode)
317: as.vector(x, mode)
316: as.vector(x, mode)
315: as.vector(x, mode)
314: as.vector(x, mode)
313: as.vector(x, mode)
312: as.vector(x, mode)
311: as.vector(x, mode)
310: as.vector(x, mode)
309: as.vector(x, mode)
308: as.vector(x, mode)
307: as.vector(x, mode)
306: as.vector(x, mode)
305: as.vector(x, mode)
304: as.vector(x, mode)
303: as.vector(x, mode)
302: as.vector(x, mode)
301: as.vector(x, mode)
300: as.vector(x, mode)
299: as.vector(x, mode)
298: as.vector(x, mode)
297: as.vector(x, mode)
296: as.vector(x, mode)
295: as.vector(x, mode)
294: as.vector(x, mode)
293: as.vector(x, mode)
292: as.vector(x, mode)
291: as.vector(x, mode)
290: as.vector(x, mode)
289: as.vector(x, mode)
288: as.vector(x, mode)
287: as.vector(x, mode)
286: as.vector(x, mode)
285: as.vector(x, mode)
284: as.vector(x, mode)
283: as.vector(x, mode)
282: as.vector(x, mode)
281: as.vector(x, mode)
280: as.vector(x, mode)
279: as.vector(x, mode)
278: as.vector(x, mode)
277: as.vector(x, mode)
276: as.vector(x, mode)
275: as.vector(x, mode)
274: as.vector(x, mode)
273: as.vector(x, mode)
272: as.vector(x, mode)
271: as.vector(x, mode)
270: as.vector(x, mode)
269: as.vector(x, mode)
268: as.vector(x, mode)
267: as.vector(x, mode)
266: as.vector(x, mode)
265: as.vector(x, mode)
264: as.vector(x, mode)
263: as.vector(x, mode)
262: as.vector(x, mode)
261: as.vector(x, mode)
260: as.vector(x, mode)
259: as.vector(x, mode)
258: as.vector(x, mode)
257: as.vector(x, mode)
256: as.vector(x, mode)
255: as.vector(x, mode)
254: as.vector(x, mode)
253: as.vector(x, mode)
252: as.vector(x, mode)
251: as.vector(x, mode)
250: as.vector(x, mode)
249: as.vector(x, mode)
248: as.vector(x, mode)
247: as.vector(x, mode)
246: as.vector(x, mode)
245: as.vector(x, mode)
244: as.vector(x, mode)
243: as.vector(x, mode)
242: as.vector(x, mode)
241: as.vector(x, mode)
240: as.vector(x, mode)
239: as.vector(x, mode)
238: as.vector(x, mode)
237: as.vector(x, mode)
236: as.vector(x, mode)
235: as.vector(x, mode)
234: as.vector(x, mode)
233: as.vector(x, mode)
232: as.vector(x, mode)
231: as.vector(x, mode)
230: as.vector(x, mode)
229: as.vector(x, mode)
228: as.vector(x, mode)
227: as.vector(x, mode)
226: as.vector(x, mode)
225: as.vector(x, mode)
224: as.vector(x, mode)
223: as.vector(x, mode)
222: as.vector(x, mode)
221: as.vector(x, mode)
220: as.vector(x, mode)
219: as.vector(x, mode)
218: as.vector(x, mode)
217: as.vector(x, mode)
216: as.vector(x, mode)
215: as.vector(x, mode)
214: as.vector(x, mode)
213: as.vector(x, mode)
212: as.vector(x, mode)
211: as.vector(x, mode)
210: as.vector(x, mode)
209: as.vector(x, mode)
208: as.vector(x, mode)
207: as.vector(x, mode)
206: as.vector(x, mode)
205: as.vector(x, mode)
204: as.vector(x, mode)
203: as.vector(x, mode)
202: as.vector(x, mode)
201: as.vector(x, mode)
200: as.vector(x, mode)
199: as.vector(x, mode)
198: as.vector(x, mode)
197: as.vector(x, mode)
196: as.vector(x, mode)
195: as.vector(x, mode)
194: as.vector(x, mode)
193: as.vector(x, mode)
192: as.vector(x, mode)
191: as.vector(x, mode)
190: as.vector(x, mode)
189: as.vector(x, mode)
188: as.vector(x, mode)
187: as.vector(x, mode)
186: as.vector(x, mode)
185: as.vector(x, mode)
184: as.vector(x, mode)
183: as.vector(x, mode)
182: as.vector(x, mode)
181: as.vector(x, mode)
180: as.vector(x, mode)
179: as.vector(x, mode)
178: as.vector(x, mode)
177: as.vector(x, mode)
176: as.vector(x, mode)
175: as.vector(x, mode)
174: as.vector(x, mode)
173: as.vector(x, mode)
172: as.vector(x, mode)
171: as.vector(x, mode)
170: as.vector(x, mode)
169: as.vector(x, mode)
168: as.vector(x, mode)
167: as.vector(x, mode)
166: as.vector(x, mode)
165: as.vector(x, mode)
164: as.vector(x, mode)
163: as.vector(x, mode)
162: as.vector(x, mode)
161: as.vector(x, mode)
160: as.vector(x, mode)
159: as.vector(x, mode)
158: as.vector(x, mode)
157: as.vector(x, mode)
156: as.vector(x, mode)
155: as.vector(x, mode)
154: as.vector(x, mode)
153: as.vector(x, mode)
152: as.vector(x, mode)
151: as.vector(x, mode)
150: as.vector(x, mode)
149: as.vector(x, mode)
148: as.vector(x, mode)
147: as.vector(x, mode)
146: as.vector(x, mode)
145: as.vector(x, mode)
144: as.vector(x, mode)
143: as.vector(x, mode)
142: as.vector(x, mode)
141: as.vector(x, mode)
140: as.vector(x, mode)
139: as.vector(x, mode)
138: as.vector(x, mode)
137: as.vector(x, mode)
136: as.vector(x, mode)
135: as.vector(x, mode)
134: as.vector(x, mode)
133: as.vector(x, mode)
132: as.vector(x, mode)
131: as.vector(x, mode)
130: as.vector(x, mode)
129: as.vector(x, mode)
128: as.vector(x, mode)
127: as.vector(x, mode)
126: as.vector(x, mode)
125: as.vector(x, mode)
124: as.vector(x, mode)
123: as.vector(x, mode)
122: as.vector(x, mode)
121: as.vector(x, mode)
120: as.vector(x, mode)
119: as.vector(x, mode)
118: as.vector(x, mode)
117: as.vector(x, mode)
116: as.vector(x, mode)
115: as.vector(x, mode)
114: as.vector(x, mode)
113: as.vector(x, mode)
112: as.vector(x, mode)
111: as.vector(x, mode)
110: as.vector(x, mode)
109: as.vector(x, mode)
108: as.vector(x, mode)
107: as.vector(x, mode)
106: as.vector(x, mode)
105: as.vector(x, mode)
104: as.vector(x, mode)
103: as.vector(x, mode)
102: as.vector(x, mode)
101: as.vector(x, mode)
100: as.vector(x, mode)
99: as.vector(x, mode)
98: as.vector(x, mode)
97: as.vector(x, mode)
96: as.vector(x, mode)
95: as.vector(x, mode)
94: as.vector(x, mode)
93: as.vector(x, mode)
92: as.vector(x, mode)
91: as.vector(x, mode)
90: as.vector(x, mode)
89: as.vector(x, mode)
88: as.vector(x, mode)
87: as.vector(x, mode)
86: as.vector(x, mode)
85: as.vector(x, mode)
84: as.vector(x, mode)
83: as.vector(x, mode)
82: as.vector(x, mode)
81: as.vector(x, mode)
80: as.vector(x, mode)
79: as.vector(x, mode)
78: as.vector(x, mode)
77: as.vector(x, mode)
76: as.vector(x, mode)
75: as.vector(x, mode)
74: as.vector(x, mode)
73: as.vector(x, mode)
72: as.vector(x, mode)
71: as.vector(x, mode)
70: as.vector(x, mode)
69: as.vector(x, mode)
68: as.vector(x, mode)
67: as.vector(x, mode)
66: as.vector(x, mode)
65: as.vector(x, mode)
64: as.vector(x, mode)
63: as.vector(x, mode)
62: as.vector(x, mode)
61: as.vector(x, mode)
60: as.vector(x, mode)
59: as.vector(x, mode)
58: as.vector(x, mode)
57: as.vector(x, mode)
56: as.vector(x, mode)
55: as.vector(x, mode)
54: as.vector(x, mode)
53: as.vector(x, mode)
52: as.vector(x, mode)
51: as.vector(x, mode)
50: as.vector(x, mode)
49: as.vector(x, mode)
48: as.vector(x, mode)
47: as.vector(x, mode)
46: as.vector(x, mode)
45: as.vector(x, mode)
44: as.vector(x, mode)
43: as.vector(x, mode)
42: as.vector(x, mode)
41: as.vector(x, mode)
40: as.vector(x, mode)
39: as.vector(x, mode)
38: as.vector(x, mode)
37: as.vector(x, mode)
36: as.vector(x, mode)
35: as.vector(x, mode)
34: as.vector(x, mode)
33: as.vector(x, mode)
32: as.vector(x, mode)
31: as.vector(x, mode)
30: as.vector(x, mode)
29: as.vector(x, mode)
28: as.vector(x, mode)
27: as.vector(x, mode)
26: as.vector(x, mode)
25: as.vector(x, mode)
24: as.vector(x, mode)
23: as.vector(x, mode)
22: as.vector(x, mode)
21: as.vector(x, mode)
20: as.vector(x, mode)
19: as.vector(x, mode)
18: as.vector(x, mode)
17: as.vector(x, mode)
16: as.vector(x, mode)
15: as.vector(x, mode)
14: as.vector(x, mode)
13: as.vector(x, mode)
12: as.vector(x, mode)
11: as.vector(x, mode)
10: as.vector(x, mode)
9: as.vector(x, "character")
8: as.vector(x, "character")
7: as.character.default(statement)
6: as.character(statement)
5: sqliteSendQuery(conn, statement)
4: .local(conn, statement, ...)
3: DBI::dbSendQuery(conn, query)
2: DBI::dbSendQuery(conn, query)
1: (function (sql, outputFile, options) 
   {
       is_sql_update_query <- function(query) {
       query <- gsub("^\\s*--.*\n", "", query)
       if (grepl("^\\s*\\/\\*.*", query)) {
           query <- gsub(".*\\*\\/", "", query)
       }
       grepl("^\\s*(INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE|CREATE).*", query, 
           ignore.case = TRUE)
       }
       dir.create(dirname(outputFile), recursive = TRUE, showWarnings = FALSE)
       max.print <- if (is.null(options$max.print)) 
       getOption("max.print", 1000)
       else as.numeric(options$max.print)
       max.print <- if (is.null(options$sql.max.print)) 
       max.print
       else as.numeric(options$sql.max.print)
       if (is.null(options$connection)) 
       stop("The 'connection' option (DBI connection) is required for sql chunks.")
       conn <- get(options$connection, envir = globalenv())
       if (is.null(conn)) 
       stop("The 'connection' option must be a valid DBI connection.")
       varnames_from_sql <- function(conn, sql) {
       varPos <- DBI::sqlParseVariables(conn, sql)
       if (length(varPos$start) > 0) {
           varNames <- substring(sql, varPos$start, varPos$end)
           sub("^\\?", "", varNames)
       }
       }
       mexists <- function(x, env = globalenv(), inherits = TRUE) {
       vapply(x, exists, logical(1), where = env, inherits = inherits)
       }
       interpolate_from_env <- function(conn, sql, env = globalenv(), 
       inherits = TRUE) {
       names <- unique(varnames_from_sql(conn, sql))
       names_missing <- names[!mexists(names, env, inherits)]
       if (length(names_missing) > 0) {
           stop("Object(s) not found: ", paste("\"", names_missing, 
               "\"", collapse = ", "))
       }
       args <- if (length(names) > 0) 
           setNames(mget(names, envir = env, inherits = inherits), 
               names)
       do.call(DBI::sqlInterpolate, c(list(conn, sql), args))
       }
       varname <- options$output.var
       query <- interpolate_from_env(conn, sql)
       if (is.null(varname) && max.print > 0 && !is_sql_update_query(query)) {
       res <- DBI::dbSendQuery(conn, query)
       data <- DBI::dbFetch(res, n = max.print)
       DBI::dbClearResult(res)
       }
       else {
       data <- DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, query)
       }
       if (!is.null(varname)) {
       assign(varname, data, envir = globalenv())
       }
       else {
       x <- data
       save(x, file = outputFile)
       }
   })("SELECT * FROM EVENTS_ID", "/home/.rstudio-desktop/notebooks/567F01E3-Notebook/1/61A0FD15/csyikkfh4nozt/00006b.rdf", 
       list(connection = "db", engine = "sql", label = "unnamed-chunk-7", 
       max.print = 10))
```

If I run `Cstack_info()` after the error I get the following

```
   size    current  direction eval_depth 
7969177      15104          1          2
```

Comment: I ran into similar issues without ever using R notebook and SQL. This may happen if a pretty large string is either returned from the DB or passed to DB as a query string. Also, I dunno whether max.print is equal to LIMIT or whether it's just a print methods that doesn't effect the query at all.  Maybe a `Cstack_info()` might help to gain further insight. Also, is there any particular reason why you wan't to use the SQL chunks. I think R is perfectly fine here and you can still display the results using R markdown.

Comment: I think the `max.print` does something similar to `LIMIT`. If I run for example `SELECT * FROM EVENTS_ID LIMIT 10` I am still getting the same error. I will edit the result of `Cstack_info()` into the question. With regards to wanting to use the SQL chunks, it doesn't really matter but I quite liked the display without the `dbGetQuery` i.e. purely aesthetic thing.